# PDF Output of Grids and Number Fields in Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

I was testing the demo orbeon form builder and repeating grids did not break between PDF output pages correctly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgpbD.png

As you can see, the line seems to abruptly break on the right, and the bottom line on the last cell didn't show up.

Is there a way to remedy this?

Also, how do I get number fields to not print to pdf with commas (for example 100100 prints as 100,100 in the pdf output even if I set the data type to integer and it displays correctly on screen).

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: This should be considered a bug. It's not clear how easy it is to fix as we use a library for rendering.

Question 2: At this time, it's not possible to set a different format for number fields in automatic PDF mode. I added an RFE:

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1567

But you could change the format globally with:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.number.grouping-separator"            value=""/>
```